# XSLT transformation to remove space within element

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am a bit new to XSLT stuff. The problem is that I need to get rid of whitespaces within certain elements in my input XML. For example

```
<element id="12">


</element>
```

should  be transformed into

```
<element id="12"></element>
```

and also

```
<element id="12">

something

</element>
```

into

```
<element id="12">something</element>
```

and the rest of the xml should remain the same. Is this kind of transformation possible with xsl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you like to do is an [Identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT).

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks, man)) that works! btw, what if I want to limit this transformation to a specific tag? Should I just put it strip-space elements="specificTag"?

Comment: Change the match="text()" template to: `<xsl:template match="element/text()">` and and more of them for each "specific tag".

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this will help you.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:normalize-space()"/> <!-- fn is the prefix bound to xpath functions -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hmm... it produced completely empty file ))

Comment: Bro, my answer is to help you with getting away from the spaces in your text nodes. You must have the copy logic. Anyway, you got it working through the another answer posted; with the logic I have posted here.

Comment: it's just that I know nothing when it comes to xslt stuff. Ur input is appreciated )