# best way for parsing an xml string and trimming spaces for specific tags using java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Imagine i have an xml-formatted string

`String gandalfSchema = "<Wizard><Name>  Gandalf  </Name><God Mode>Off</God Mode></Wizard>";`

I want to remove all leading and trailing spaces for values for multiple tags; in this case `Gandalf` in `<Name>`.

I'm not sure if the following way is the best:

```
String nameBeginIndex = gandalfSchema.substring("<Name>");
String nameEndIndex = gandalfSchema.substring("</Name>");
String nameRaw = gandalfSchema.substring(nameBeginIndex+6,nameEndIndex);
String nameProcessed = nameRaw;
String stringBeforeNameRaw = gandalfSchema.substring(nameBeginIndex);
String stringAfterNameRaw = gandalfSchema.substring(nameEndIndex);
gandalfSchema = stringBeforeNameRaw + nameProcessed + stringAfterNameRaw
```

Now imagine doing the above for 3-4 tags, i think that is bad practice. Is there a library, or convention in Java for this that I may have overlooked?

Comment: You're looking for XML parsers.  This is definitely not the best way to go about it, as this isn't a portable solution.

Comment: With an XML library (or reader) it is easy to traverse through the entire structure and fix up the relevant Text nodes. In general, for any external format (eg. XML, JSON, Excel) it is "bad practice" to generate, modify, or consume the raw data outside of tooling/libraries/adapters designed for the purpose.

Comment: @Makoto  do you have a preferred XML reader then?

Comment: `<Gode Mode>` is not a valid XML element.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is XML Parsers. There are already so many available. Google it.
Why reinvent the wheel, unless you're trying to build new parser itself (which is quite unlikely).

Comment: Can XML parser parse `<God Mode>`?

Comment: no they cannot. And they shouldn't. Because <God Mode> is invalid xml element name as per XML specs. Question was about how to parse the xml, not about validity of xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT with [Java Transformer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933351/xslt-transformation-to-remove-space-within-element) is a similar example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JaxB and actually create objects based on your xml

**Wizard Class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Wizard")
public class Wizard {

    private String name;
    private String godMode;


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGodMode() {
        return this.godMode;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="GodMode")
    public void setGodMode(String godMode) {
        this.godMode = godMode;
    }
}
```

Then use an unmarshalled to get the object from xml

**Unmarshaller**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wizard.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader("<Wizard><Name> Gandalf </Name><GodMode>Off</GodMode></Wizard>");
Wizard wizard = (Wizard) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

and then you can do what ever you want with it. Also "God Mode" has a space and that does not work for element names (if possible change this, or you might have to do a find replace on this before unmarshalling).

Comment: if i were to remove the space from `<God Mode>` to 'GodMode', the jaxb example will work?

Comment: Yes it will work, I dropped the marshaller into a main method and tested it, you could do the same.

Comment: thanks and if i were to convert the `Wizard` object back into a string i'll just marshal it back right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes use jaxb that comes with Java and using any IDE you can create the xml classes and can Marshall and uarshall in much better and easier way
You need to know your Xsd and that you can get online if you have the xml ready