# Remove Leading & Trailing Whitespaces from XML Node value

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I am looking for a way to remove leading and trailing whitespaces from a XML node's value. Given the following basic example:

```
<CAR>
  <MAKE>   Ford   </MAKE>
  <COLOR>   Yellow  </COLOR>
  <!--<YEAR>  1987   </YEAR>-->
</CAR>
```

I need to get the following output:

```
<CAR>
<MAKE>Ford</MAKE>
  <COLOR>Yellow</COLOR>
  <!--<YEAR>  1987   </YEAR>-->
</CAR>
```

I managed to get all of this done by successively applying the following two regex:

```
>\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9^<]*

[^a-zA-Z0-9^>]*\s*</
```

As my knowledge regarding regex is very limited, this was all I could come up with. The problem is that I ended up with a broken XML document whenever the file contained comments.

So, can anyone help me with getting an expression that successfully removes leading and trailing whitespaces from the values while leaving any comments intact?

I hope, I made myself clear.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried [\S] (capital s)

Comment: There's a cool website for trying out your regex : http://regexr.com/

Try it. It might help :D

Comment: I would suggest an alternate approach to the problem. You could try XSLT to remove the spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933351/xslt-transformation-to-remove-space-within-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no need for regexes here, moreover, you will need in any case to loop over your xml nodes, so why not simply looping over your node values and doing `.Trim()` on them ?

For example:

```
    var xml = XDocument.Load("D:/myXml.xml");

    foreach (var node in xml.Root.Elements())
    {
        foreach (var child in node.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}]", child.Value.Trim()));
        }
    }
```

My sample xml file:

[image]

The output: (I surrounded it with [ ] so you can see the whitespaces are gone)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I must have had my blinders on. I went with a similar solution to yours. Sometimes all it needs is a additional pair of eyes to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Regex.Replace(input string, @"(([^\s]+)\s+)", "$2");`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not using Regex then this works:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<CAR>
  <MAKE>   Ford   </MAKE>
  <COLOR>   Yellow  </COLOR>
  <!--<YEAR>  1987   </YEAR>-->
</CAR>");

foreach (var xe in doc.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    .Select(x => x.Parent)
    .ToArray())
{
    xe.Value = xe.Value.Trim();
}
```

It updates the `doc` and gives me this:

```
<CAR>
  <MAKE>Ford</MAKE>
  <COLOR>Yellow</COLOR>
  <!--<YEAR>  1987   </YEAR>-->
</CAR>
```

Comment: Cheers, I will keep this in mind in case I'll ever find myself in a similar situation. If I had enough reputation, I'd give you +1.